# AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, pytorch

Recently, I've run this project（https://github.com/milesial/Pytorch-UNet）and when I run predict.py, it came to this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 131, in <module>
    device=device)
  File "predict.py", line 43, in predict_img
    transforms.Resize(full_img.shape[2]),
AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Then I check the code and I find that this version is extremely similar to the version before

previous version:

```
img_height = full_img.size[1]
        tf = transforms.Compose(
            [
                transforms.ToPILImage(),
                transforms.Resize(img_height),
                transforms.ToTensor()
            ]
        )
```

present version:

```
    tf = transforms.Compose(
        [
            transforms.ToPILImage(),
            transforms.Resize(full_img.shape[1]),
            transforms.ToTensor()
        ]
    )
```

I don't know what had happened but if any friend know something about this question I will be great gratefull to you! Thanks!

Comment: you gan get image height for PIL using `full_img.size[1]` refer [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.size)

Comment: thx very much! It seems like png picture cannot use '.shape[2]'.... I change it into '.width' and finally succesfully run the project~

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis to close up 'Compose'